# Efficient Excel formula for returning multiple matches from a large number of rows

Tags: arrays, excel, large-data

I'm stumped by a major issue. I have a data set consisting of about 16000 rows (could be more in future). This list is basically a price list containing products and their corresponding installation fees. Now the products are classified by the following hierarchy: City -> Category -> Rating/Type. Before I was using named ranges to refer to each set by concatenating City & Category & Rating (_XYZ_SPC_9.5). This resulted in about 1500 named ranges which inflated the size of the Excel file. So I decided to calculate the products on-the-fly using inputs from the user. I have tried array formulas and simple formulas but they take some time to calculate (16000 rows!!) which is not acceptable from a usability perspective; our sales people are very particular about how much time they have to spend on the tool.

I have uploaded a sample file at:
[Price List Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fghe24tuu9zx6dh/Sample_Data2.xlsx)

Formulas that I have used so far are:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$6:$H$15000, SMALL(INDEX(($AE$9=$R$6:$R$15000)*(MATCH(ROW($R$6:$R$15000), ROW($R$6:$R$15000)))+($AE$9<>$R$6:$R$15000)*15000, 0, 0), AC3)),"Not Available")

{=IFERROR(INDEX(ref_PRICE_LIST!$H$6:$H$16074,MATCH(INDEX(ref_PRICE_LIST!$H$6:$H$16074,(SMALL(IF(IF(RIGHT($AE$3,3)="All",ref_PRICE_LIST!$Z$6:$Z$16074,ref_PRICE_LIST!$R$6:$R$16074)=$AE$3,ROW(ref_PRICE_LIST!$H$6:$H$16074)-ROW(ref_PRICE_LIST!$H$6)+1),$AC3))),ref_PRICE_LIST!$H$6:$H$16074,0),1),"Not Available")}
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need a real database.

Comment: No it has to be offline and Excel based only.

Comment: How does the posted formulas relate to the sample data? They include ranges and sheets not in the sample!

Comment: Please see updated file [Sample Data 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fghe24tuu9zx6dh/Sample_Data2.xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to speed this up is to split the formula into a helper column `K` and a reult column `L`

Helper Column (copy down for all 16,000 data rows)

```
=IF($D:$D=$O$2,ROW(),"")
```

Result column (starting at `L2`, copy down as many as you need)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F,SMALL($K:$K,ROW()-1)),"Not available")
```

I've tested this with about 150,000 rows and it updates in < 1s

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for the help; it works well. But I do have one more request: What if I want to display all the products in one category irrespective of the "rating"? Something to the effect "_AT1_SPC_ALL". 
Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: BTW: is there anyway I can accomplish this using Pivot Tables?